# Probability of skewed coin vs fair coin given conditions.

Tags: probability

I'm solving the following problem:

We have 2 coins, Coin A is heads with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ and Coin B is heads with probability $\frac{2}{3}$. We choose a random coin with equal chance of each one being picked. We flip the chosen coin twice without knowing which one we've picked. What is the probability that we have the skewed coin given that the first toss is heads and the second toss is tails? What is the probability that we have the skewed coin given that the two tosses are different?

Let $A$ be the event that we have chosen coin $A$. Let $H_1$ be the event that the first toss is heads and lets $T_2$ be the event that the second toss is tails. Let $D$ be the event that the two coin tosses are different.

By Bayes and LOTP we get that \begin{align}P(A^c | H_1 \cap T_2 ) &= \dfrac{P(H_1 \cap T_2 | A^c)P(A^c)}{P(H_1 \cap T_2)} = \dfrac{P(H_1 \cap T_2 | A^c)P(A^c)}{P(H_1 \cap T_2 | A)P(A) + P(H_1 \cap T_2 | A^c)P(A^c)}\\
&=\dfrac{\frac{2}{9}\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{9}\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{8}{17}\end{align}

\begin{align}
P(A^c | D ) &= \dfrac{P(D | A^c)P(A^c)}{P(D)} = \dfrac{P(D | A^c)P(A^c)}{P(D | A)P(A) + P(D | A^c)P(A^c)}\\
&=\dfrac{\frac{4}{9}\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2} + \frac{4}{9}\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{8}{17}\end{align}

This seems wrong to me. I'm reminded of the boy-girl paradox where in the first case we have more information then the second so it should be a different probability. Has something gone wrong or is there a hidden symmetry?

EDIT: I think I have noticed the problem, $P(D | A)$ isnt 1/4 but 1/2? That would change things. Am I correct?

Comment: Both your answers are correct. In the second scenario you've to find probability of $P(HT \cup TH)$, which is equal to $2P(HT)$. This $2$ is being cancelled from both numerator and denominator which leads to same answers.

Comment: Oooooohhh right! That makes sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has already been answered in the comments.

Another way to look at it is to note that the count of successful outcomes is a sufficient statistic for a Bernoulli experiment. That is, all information that the data contains about the parameter of the distribution is in that count, and the rest of the information in the data, namely the order of the outcomes, contains no information about the parameter. Since the two scenarios only differ in your knowledge about the order, they don't differ in your knowledge about the parameter.